# remap the top number keys to use the symbols and numbers with the shift key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

As a developer I often have to write a lot of % $ # symbols in my code.  It is extra work over a day to keep hitting shift so obviously this will be a real functional improvement for programming to remap the top row of number keys to the symbols by default and the number via plus shift.  I have a numeric keypad that I use for numbers.  I do see a few posts on how to re-map the shift keys but that is not what I want to do.  I also have tried to use xev but I'm not sure if it understands what shift+1 is like is it just telling me what the shift key is?  Anyway it would be really sweet if there is a simple gui to do this but if not I can rewrite a preference file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gui tool to remap keys. It is called dconf-tools (install via apt). Under org -> gnome -> desktop -> input-sources there are xkb-options. I used this to switch escape and capslock.

EDIT: go to /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols . There you'll find abbreviations for different languages. Open your language with sudo nano ... In the file you'll see lines like: '1, exclam, ...' just put the command for the symbol first and the number second and it will be switched around.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I found the file "us" in the folder you described  and sudo opened it in gedit.   and change     key <AE01> { [    exclam, 1  ] };
    key <AE02> { [   2, at  ] };
    key <AE03> { [   3, numbersign ] };  you can see i reversed the order for 1 but I don't see a change what do I need to do next?

Comment: For testing purposes I did this for a different language and when I changed my keyboard Settings to this language it worked (without restart). So maybe try to switch to another language and back to US or try a restart.i'll investigate when I get to my PC.

Comment: You are correct! I just had to add another keyboard, could be any keyboard, Chinese even then remove this new keyboard and then the new key mapping worked.  Must need that to trigger the change.

Comment: @flyingdrifter How was your experience with this setting (layout)? Did you keep it in the last years?